# Convert date string to a different format in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Getting the date in bash works something like this:

```
now=$(date)
echo "Current date: $now"
```

It returns:

```
Current date: Mon Nov 28 11:34:55 NZDT 2016
```

I need to store the date in a variable where the date is in a format like this:

```
20161128
```

How can I convert the date format into the format I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use any format with +%

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

Output

```
20161127
```